# DrawerLayout without Support Library for MinSDK >= 15

Tags: android, drawerlayout

Why is the DrawerLayout only available in the Support Library and not in the standard API?

I was trying to include it for a Project with minSDK 15 and Android Studio couldn't resolve the Class.
Compiling with the v4 Support Library did the trick though, so I wondered why that's the case.

Comment: Not everything in the Support Package is necessarily part of the Android SDK at some level. `ViewPager`, `SlidingPaneLayout`, and others fall into the same camp. The only people who can answer "why?" definitively are Googlers, who are unlikely to notice this question. All anyone else can do is supply an opinion or guess, neither of which are what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: Ok sorry if this wasn't the right place to post it. Where should I go with such general questions the next time?

Comment: It's not so much a "general" question as one that is unlikely to have a definitive answer that the community can give. Stack Overflow is for "how do I do X?" more so than "why did Google do Y?". As to where to ask those "why?" questions, I don't have a great answer, though [other Android developer support sites](http://www.andglobe.com) may accept such questions.